# Price mark up does not display for 2 sites in Google, but is fine for our other 4 sites

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

We have eCommerce sites in 6 different countries and have had schema mark up for product data for a couple of years.  However the Price snippets do not display for our sites in Indonesia and Thailand, but work fine for our sites in Malaysia, Philippines, Singapore and Vietnam.

I noticed that we weren't including the SKU number in our mark up, which is a requirement according to Google specs, so we recently updated our Mark up to include the SKU and also changed from Microdata mark up to using JSON mark up (for ease of implementation).

However after waiting two weeks after implementation (for SERPs to update) we see for Indonesia and Thailand the price is still not displaying for single product mark up, but is appearing when we have multiple offers on a product page. (this is a new feature, we did not used to have mark up when we had multiple offers).

Below are  two screen shots from the SERPs for our Thai and Indonesian site, showing the price appearing for multiple offers but not for single products.

**Thai site:**

[image: Google Search results for the Thai site]

**Indonesia site:**

[image: Google Search results for the Indonesia site]

If you click the links below you will see that the price appears on both single and multiple offers pages on our Malaysia, Philippines, Singapore and Vietnam sites.

- [Malaysian site](https://www.google.com.my/search?num=100&espv=2&q=site:lazada.com.my%20inurl:html&oq=site:lazada.com.my%20inurl:html&gs_l=serp.3...1721801.1724132.0.1724515.7.6.1.0.0.0.113.448.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.9qzlAMqQPSk&gws_rd=cr&ei=4xCkV_-7KYqCvQTQ2Lz4Dg)
- [Philippine site](https://www.google.com.my/search?num=100&espv=2&q=site:lazada.com.my%20inurl:html&oq=site:lazada.com.my%20inurl:html&gs_l=serp.3...1721801.1724132.0.1724515.7.6.1.0.0.0.113.448.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.9qzlAMqQPSk&gws_rd=cr&ei=4xCkV_-7KYqCvQTQ2Lz4Dg#q=site:lazada.com.ph%20inurl:html)
- [Singapore Site](https://www.google.com.my/search?num=100&espv=2&q=site:lazada.com.my%20inurl:html&oq=site:lazada.com.my%20inurl:html&gs_l=serp.3...1721801.1724132.0.1724515.7.6.1.0.0.0.113.448.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.9qzlAMqQPSk&gws_rd=cr&ei=4xCkV_-7KYqCvQTQ2Lz4Dg#q=site:lazada.sg%20inurl:html)
- [Vietnamese Site](https://www.google.com.my/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1920&bih=947&q=site:lazada.vn%20inurl:html&oq=site:lazada.vn%20inurl:html&gs_l=serp.12...32126.32233.3.36337.2.2.0.0.0.0.132.215.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.RJkCHMZguRs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.129391328,d.c2I&ech=1&psi=ERGkV_LLLcXgvgT29p_IBg.1470370065825.9&ei=ixGkV-rnNIfrvgT_7aPwAw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1)

There are no errors for Structured Data in Search Console and no errors when testing pages with Google's structured data testing tool. There is no difference in the mark up code between the different country sites.

So my question is why historically have we never had price appearing for our Thai and Indonesian sites, and why are we only getting it on pages with multiple offers now?

Comment: I did a thorough audit, the domains are trusted, the markup works fine, there's no obvious differences between those that work and those that don't. I would put this down to Google being temperamental!

Comment: @Yhorian Google being temperamental? What? Nah! Never!! ;-) Google is perfect! Google is our precious and beloved search Daddy. (*wisper*) Be careful, there are cameras everywhere. They can hear you!

Comment: are you able to find a solution for your issue after this long time?